# Unexpected behaviour of ILoggerFactory in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to add a logger for a specifc dbContext. For example I have the next code:

```
var dbContextOptionsBuilder1 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
dbContextOptionsBuilder1.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
var dbContext1 = new DbContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder1.Options);
var loggerFactory1 = dbContext1.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory1.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider());

var dbContextOptionsBuilder2 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
dbContextOptionsBuilder2.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
var dbContext2 = new DbContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder2.Options);
var loggerFactory2 = dbContext2.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

If I expand non-public members of `loggerFactory1` I will see my CustomLoggerProvider that I added (_providerRegistrations = Count = 1). But If I expand non-public members of `loggerFactory2` I will see the same CustomLoggerProvider (_providerRegistrations = Count = 1) although I didn't add it to `dbContext2`.

Also I got another unexpected behaviour in the next code:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbService dbService;
    public MyDbContext(IDbService dbService, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}

var dbContextOptionsBuilder1 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
dbContextOptionsBuilder1.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
var dbContext1 = new DbContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder1.Options);
var loggerFactory1 = dbContext1.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory1.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider());

var dbContextOptionsBuilder2 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
dbContextOptionsBuilder2.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
var dbContext2 = new DbContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder2.Options);
var loggerFactory2 = dbContext2.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

var dbContextOptionsBuilder3 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
dbContextOptionsBuilder3.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
var dbContext3 = new MyDbContext(new DbService(), dbContextOptionsBuilder3.Options);
var loggerFactory3 = dbContext3.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory3.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider());

var dbContextOptionsBuilder4 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
dbContextOptionsBuilder4.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
var dbContext4 = new MyDbContext(new DbService(), dbContextOptionsBuilder4.Options);
var loggerFactory4 = dbContext4.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

In this case I got 1 CustomLoggerProvider in `dbContext3` (_providerRegistrations = Count = 1) and the same logger in `dbContext4` (_providerRegistrations = Count = 1). So there is no relationship between `dbContext1`, `dbContext2` and `dbContext3`, `dbContext4`.
So if I add one more CustomLoggerProvider to `dbContext1` I will get the next result:

```
dbContext1: 2 CustomLoggerProvider (_providerRegistrations = Count = 2)
dbContext2: 2 CustomLoggerProvider (_providerRegistrations = Count = 2)
dbContext3: 1 CustomLoggerProvider (_providerRegistrations = Count = 1)
dbContext4: 1 CustomLoggerProvider (_providerRegistrations = Count = 1)
```

What is the right way to work with ILoggerFactory?

Comment: It will all make sense if you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging). The logger factory is a singleton (that is, if you initialized it as recommended).

Comment: See EF Core documentation - [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging). It explicitly states that `ILoggerFactory` is singleton and contains a warning *"It is very important that applications do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance for each context instance. Doing so will result in a memory leak and poor performance.*". In other words, logging per db context is not supported.